# Printing text on image in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, dictionary

I have made a dictionary,done some calculations and returned some values. Now i'm trying to print those returned values on an image, but I get this error:

```
expected string or Unicode object, int found
```

let's say my returned value is:

```
 (58, 47, 88.0)
```

and I'm using the following to display it on a screen:

```
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(img, T ,(619,351), font, 1,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Also, I want to be able to display on the image: `T = (58, 47, 88.0)`

Comment: I believe putText expects a sting input and you're inserting Int which causes the error

Comment: it's probably as simple as `cv2.putText(img, str(T), ...)`

Comment: @berak * facepalm * Thank you. You rock!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be going in right direction I guess, The code looks good enough, But there is a `TypeError` which indicates that you have passed an Integer in place of a string and most probably, that mistake must be somewhere in the value of `T`, Check if  it's of type `int` , you can always check the type of any variable using `type(T)`, If it returns `int` then you probably need to typecast the variable as `str(T)` so the final code may look like:

```
if not type(T) is str:
    try:
        cv2.putText(img, str(T) ,(619,351), font, 1,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    except Exception,e:
        print e
```

Answer (score 1):

putting str() around the text to be printed really works for me here. I m surprised the error was showing for a different argument even though a previous argument had the actual error